# how to return a value if a condition on one column is null

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

i what part of a column to fill another full column column if the first cell is null

for instance this sheet {sheet 1} is the sheet i want the data in from the other sheet {sheet 2} to fill

(Please view imgs as they are vital to the question)

[{Sheet1}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoPGo.png)

this is the other spreadsheet i want the data to be extracted from

[{Sheet2}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywLn7.png)

so i want column 1, 2, 3 (in {sheet 2} ) to be filled with contents from column 1, 2, 5 in {sheet 1} ONLY IF Column 1 in {sheet 1} = Column 1 in {sheet 2} which is null.

Essentially I want to I want column one, three and five (in sheet 1) to fill in sheet 2 columns 1, 2 and 3 only if column one in sheet 1 is null. See attached photos

i tried with VLOOKUP but no luck

thanks a bunch

Comment: @Please be more specific.

Comment: I want column one, three and five (in sheet 1) to fill in sheet 2 columns 1, 2 and 3 only if column one in sheet 1 is null. See attached photos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Seamus if i understand correctly try:

Sheet 2

```
Column 1=IF(Sheet1!$A$1="Null",Sheet1!A1,"")
Column 2=IF(Sheet1!$A$1="Null",Sheet1!C1,"")
Column 3=IF(Sheet1!$A$1="Null",Sheet1!E1,"")
```

If the value you are looking for is an empty cell try:

```
Column 1=IF(Sheet1!$A$1="",Sheet1!A1,"")
Column 2=IF(Sheet1!$A$1="",Sheet1!C1,"")
Column 3=IF(Sheet1!$A$1="",Sheet1!E1,"")
```

Comment: Works Great! Thanks Alot